# MvvmCross messenger plugin sample applications

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

Kindly suggest or refer a link for getting clear idea for Messenger in MVVM CROSS.

Note: I have gone through the [N-09-Location And Message](https://github.com/MvvmCross/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/tree/master/N-09-Location%20And%20Message) application but still not clear with myself.

Comment: "still not clear with myself." isn't really a very easy question for anyone to answer. Please ask details. What are you trying to do? What have you tried? What errors have you seen? The more detail you provide in questions, the more detail answerers can provide in answers.

Comment: I need to communicate two view models(When one view model property is changed, need to fire another view model property changed). I have tried messenger but cant achieve. Kindly suggest.

Comment: Link you have posted ... Has the example easy to understand, I tried and it works. Did you run the sample

Answer (score 4):

The Messenger is discussed and shown in several N+1 videos: N=9 and N=12 http://mvvmcross.wordpress.com/

The plugin is discussed in the Wiki - https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/MvvmCross-plugins#messenger

Several of the tutorial examples use the messenger too - https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/search?q=messenger&ref=cmdform

There are lots of general "Messenger pattern" articles around on the web - e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj694937.aspx

Comment: Some Links  are Expired, Please Update the links :P

Answer (score 3):

If you refer to MvxMessenger, try reading this https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/View-Model-Lifecycle#viewmodel-deactivation-activation-and-destruction.